# Generating world wide unique hashes

Tags: c#

I'm trying to generate world wide unique hashes (or have an astronomically small chance of generating collisions) by performing a web request at google.com and SHA256 hashing the request headers from the request.

The aim is to generate these unique hashes without using the system's cryptographic random number generator. The reason for this is that these hashes are not used for security.

How likely is it that the resulting hashes are really world wide unique?

Working example code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://google.com");

        request.Timeout = 1000;

        try
        {
            WebHeaderCollection responseHeaders = request.GetResponse().Headers;
            StringBuilder headerString = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.Count; i++)
                headerString.Append(responseHeaders.Get(i));

            Console.WriteLine(headerString.ToString());

            byte[] hash = new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headerString.ToString()));

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(hash));
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Time out or unable to perform request.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29650/sha-256-almost-unique

Comment: Aweful exception handling.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Guid? 
The chance of duplicates is astronimical: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions

Comment: There are several types of GUIDs and there are problems associated with some of them. I'm trying to avoid these problems by using more than just a GUID (local drives info, network info, environment block, timezone info, etc). It's overkill, but that's intentional.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why you need a hashing function. A hashing function is needed to produce the same result for a given input. But if you have more or less random input like the output from Google, then it seems you don't need the hashing, you just need a unique number.

For unique numbers, I think your approach is a bad idea. If only once the headers sent by Google are the same, then the hash will also be the same and no longer unique.

As far as I can see, the only header which makes the response unique is the `date` header. (I don't see the cookie header on my machine as mentioned in the comments). It has a 1 second resolution, so your implementation will return the same hash for all runs within a second.

Besides that, having a dependency to an Internet connection for such a tasks sounds like overkill.

What is typically done to generate unique identifiers (but that's not a hash): use the MAC address of the network card (which should be unique already) and combine it with the current time (in milliseconds). That's basically the idea behind [Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: The Set-Cookie header contains a big base64 string that seems quite different every time. Trying to generate world wide unique hashes isn't as easay as it may seem. Certainly without using the systems crypto PRNG.